# Countif with Index Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a column with dates (some are the same date) in column A.  I need to use index match to look up for same date within Col A AND have it count how many times "Purchases" appears in Column H within the table.  So far I have this: =COUNTIF(INDEX(H:H, MATCH(A7,A:A, 0)),"Purchase")

I feel like I am missing an additional statement because the output only shows as 1.

Thank you

Comment: Provide some dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() with an s:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A7,H:H,"Purchase")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, I would need the countif to count how many "Purchases" are in column H within a specified recurring date in column A.  

So for example, A2 = 02/03/17, the formula would have to pick up similar dates within col A and additionally look for the criteria "Purchases" in column H.

Comment: What are "similar dates"?

Comment: The formula will count every row that has `02/03/2017` in column A AND `Purchases` in Column H.  So I echo the comment what do you mean by similar? @JacobEdmond

Comment: I mean same date, so it would look for other 02/03/2017 in column A AND count "Purchases" with that date.  Does that make sense? @ScottCraner

Comment: That is what the formula does, so I ask, did you try the formula? @PeterNguyen

Comment: I did. The output was 0.  Which seems incorrect where it is suppose to be 1.

Comment: You say your original formula returned 1, which was wrong. Perhaps you need to change the A1 to A7 like in your original? Without sample data, it is unclear the exact references you require, but COUNTIFS is the function to perform what you described you needed.

Comment: Is there a way to post the data table on stackoverflow? @JacobEdmond

Comment: @PeterNguyen post a link to a picture

Comment: @PeterNguyen I was referencing A1, I changed it to A7, try the new formula first.

Comment: I hope this helps.
http://imgur.com/IcyPdYc

So in the second field it supposed to be 15

Comment: @PeterNguyen there is a problem with your data.  It appears that the dates are not true dates but text that look like dates, or sometimes when using dates the cell shows a date but there is a time factor attached to the date which would mean that the cells are not equal.  When you select A2 what does the formula bar show?

Comment: @PeterNguyen it is your data, see edit for proof that formula works.  hover over the Green triangle in the upper left corner, what does the error say?

Comment: @ScottCraner it "this cell contained a date string with only 2 digits for the year .

Comment: Fix your dates to true dates, it is not finding them as matches for some reason.  The formula is the one you want when you fix your data. It is not the formula that is wrong, sorry.

Comment: Oh don't be sorry.  Thank you so much for the help! @ScottCraner